# WPF: TIFF images with JPEG compression?

Tags: .net, wpf, encoding, jpeg, tiff

I have a large number of TIFF images that I’d need to use in a WPF program (.NET 3.5 SP1 specifically and using C#). Half of the TIFF files contain color images encoded using JPEG compression and they don’t work with WPF. The “Microsoft Office Document Imaging” application handles the files fine. As Windows itself doesn’t really like them either (can’t produce thumbnails for instance) I’m assuming this is a restriction in the standard Windows Imaging Components (WIC) libraries.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correctly read the TIFF images that are using JPEG compression with the standard .NET/WPF libraries?

Or does anyone know of any alternate third party TIFF codecs for WIC that I might be able to use to work around this issue?

Or finally are there any alternate .NET libraries for TIFF files that are still easily usable with WPF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TIFF-wrapped JPEGs come in two flavors - type 6 and type 7.  What you are describing are the type 6 TIFFs.  While Adobe has recommended for years that this type not be used (see [Tech Note 2](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/TIFFTechNote2.html) for details), several graphics packages still use it.

I know of a few commercial graphics packages for .NET that can read them such as the [Captiva ISIS PixTools](http://www.emc.com/products/detail/software/pixtools.htm) (formerly Pixtran) libraries, but do not know offhand of anything open source or otherwise free.

Comment: Actually they are type 7 files (they're created by a Win32 application we wrote and I checked the source). Microsoft Office Document Imaging opens them fine, but other Microsoft tools can't handle them (e.g. Paint or Windows Picture and Fax Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

What WPF API are you using to handle them?

Have you tried using [TiffBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder.aspx) from the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace?

Comment: I'd been simply trying to use an Image component. I tried the sample code from the MSDN article you suggested and while it works for other files, the JPEG compressed images all generate 0x88982F40 exceptions when attempting to decode the file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade to either Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 (or newer) in order to open these files natively.

Libtiff (C++) and LibTIFF.NET (.Net) should be able to open these files. Please make sure that when you build one of these libraries, that the TIFF_JPEG (both 6 and 7) are enabled in the build. Those formats are disabled in the default build settings.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for making a comment on this very old thread. I have a couple of questions for you. 1) Why isn't TIFF_JPEG enabled in the default builds? 2) Any compatibility with WPF or WIC built in?

Comment: @Scott Bussinger: (1) it requires a compatible version of libjpeg to build. In addition, it cannot guarantee correctly opening the tiff-jpeg from all vendors due to non-standardized vendor implementations. It will require a maintenance engineer to watch over and fix issues in code as they are discovered. (If you do fix some bug, libtiff welcomes you to submit your patch.) (2) WIC is dependent on the Windows OS version. Windows 7 and later versions provide native support for TIFF_JPEG.