# How to open old-style JPEG compressed TIF-Files in VisualBasic program?

Tags: vb.net, image, jpeg, gdi+, tiff

I have many tif files with old-style jpeg compression.
I need to show them in my vb.net programm in a picturebox where I am already showing "normal" TIFs and JPGs. 
It isn't working it's always throwing: 
 `"A generic error occured in GDI+" ("Allgemeiner Fehler in GDI+" in German)`

All I found about this problem is, that GDI+ isn't capable of showing old-style jpeg compressed tif files.

How am I supposed to show them now? I can't even load it in vb directly to an image variable like so:

```
Dim oldStyleTiff As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\temp\01.tif")
```

Windows isn' t showing it either, Photoshop won't open it up. Only IrfanView seems to "ignore" the problem. There are too many pictures to open them up one by one and save them as jpg via IrfanView so that I'm able to show them...

```
    picPath = Wrkbnch.getFilePath(count, conPath)

    fs = New FileStream(picPath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    pic = Image.FromStream(fs) '<--- Error occurs here
    fs.Close()

    PBox.Image = pic
```

Comment: Seems you are out of luck... But, it's not too hard to parse a TIFF structure. If you find or create such a library/tool, you can find the offsets to the JPEG tables and JPEG stream inside the TIFF, and re-create a JPEG from it. Either store it to disk or just do it in-memory and load as a normal JPEG. Keep in mind though, that there is a reason "old-style" JPEG-in-TIFF was abandoned. Don't expect to be able to read all such images...

Comment: The only long term solution to this is to convert the files to a format that is universally recognized. I am sure that there is some command line tool that would do such a conversion.

Comment: I think users idea is the best: convert the files using some tool. I think IrfanView has a batch mode, which should work

Comment: The information in [WPF: TIFF images with JPEG compression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297949/wpf-tiff-images-with-jpeg-compression) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic comment, but @Rasalas, do you have any old-style-jpeg TIFFs to share? I'm implementing a [TIFF reader](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) that attempts to read old-style-jpeg in Java, and such files are hard to come by. :-)

Comment: @haraldK I'm sorry they all have private informations on them. If I black them out I can't save it :>
I would if I could - sorry

Comment: @Rasalas No problem, I know that's quite common. Thanks for getting back to me anyway! :-)

Comment: I have the same problems while displaying old jpeg documents. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't really solve it. You could look for a Java API that can read it. Or you can use IrfanView to batch-convert all pictures to new-style jpeg compression.
I wrote a program that detects old-style jpegs and writes it in a .txt?-File in IrfanViews export/import "list style". My customer didn't want to bother with old files from his customers and his customers didn't want to pay me to do their job. I don't know where the program went. Probably sooomewhere in my archives...wasn't that problematic - it's prossible that I used a try-catch to "detect" them. Hope this here helps. @naro

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, this does not help me, because I can not make sure that IrfanView is installed.

Comment: well, either they install it and convert the old files, let someone convert them for them or they'll plain and simple will never see these pictures ever again... ;)